# MongoDB nested lookup with 3 levels and append new value to the result docs

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I need to retrieve the entire single object hierarchy from the database as a JSON. Actually the proposal about any other solution to achive this result would be highly appriciated. I decided to use MongoDB with its $lookup support.

So I have four collections:

0. **Users**

```
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "john" }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Doe" }
```

1. **Posts**

```
{"_id": "2","body": "hello", likes: []},
{"_id": "1","name": "hello 4", likes: [1,]},
```

2. **Comments**

```
{"_id": "c2","body": "hello 3",postId: "1",likes: [1,2]},
{"_id": "c1","body": "hello 2",postId: "1",likes: [1,2]},
```

3. **Replies**

```
{"_id": "r1","name": "hello 4",commentId: "c1",likes: [1]},
{"_id": "r3","name": "hello five",commentId: "c2",likes: [1,2]}
```

I basically need to retrieve all posts with all corresponding comments and comments.replies as part of my result . My aggregation:

```
  const posts = await PostModel.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "comments",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "postId",
          as: "comments",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$comments",
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "replies",
          localField: "comments._id",
          foreignField: "commentId",
          as: "comments.replies",
        },
      },
    ]).sort({
      createdAt: -1,
    });
```

[MongoDb PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gKbhmbVAvJq)

The result is pretty weird. Some records are ok. But  comments return an object . There are also some duplications on the post with _id="1".

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "comments": {
      "_id": "c2",
      "body": "hello 3",
      "likes": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "postId": "1",
      "replies": [
        {
          "_id": "r3",
          "commentId": "c2",
          "likes": [
            1,
            2
          ],
          "name": "hello five"
        }
      ]
    },
    "likes": [
      1
    ],
    "name": "hello 4"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "comments": {
      "_id": "c1",
      "body": "hello 2",
      "likes": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "postId": "1",
      "replies": [
        {
          "_id": "r1",
          "commentId": "c1",
          "likes": [
            1
          ],
          "name": "hello 4"
        }
      ]
    },
    "likes": [
      1
    ],
    "name": "hello 4"
  }
]
```

Brief, This is my expected result.

- I want to get all posts, with all comments and replies associated with them .
- I want to append a count of likes `likesCount:{$size:["likes"]}` and since I have the user auth id(`uid`) ready I want to check if the user liked the post , comment or reply based on if `isLiked: {$in:[ID(uid),"likes"]}`

Comment: you may have to group it together back with post Id  https://mongoplayground.net/p/MaGfTdTS6v0

Comment: counts of replies of each comment ?

Comment: @Beingnin how ama gonna access the replies.likes and count them tho

Comment: @Beingnin (mongoplayground.net/p/MaGfTdTS6v0)[https://mongoplayground.net/p/MaGfTdTS6v0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each post have multiple comments, after unwinding comments you need to group it together to form an array

**Update**
I have updated the fetch approach a lil bit like the below.

```
  db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "postId",
      as: "comments",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$comments",
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "replies",
      localField: "comments._id",
      foreignField: "commentId",
      as: "replies",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$replies",
    
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "replies.countOflikes": {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$replies.likes",
            []
          ]
        }
      },
      "replies.isLiked": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$replies.likes",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$item",
                        1//id of the user whom you wanna check if liked the reply
                        
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          then: false,
          else: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$comments._id",
      postId: {
        $first: "$_id"
      },
      body: {
        $first: "$body"
      },
      "comments": {
        $first: "$comments"
      },
      replies: {
        $push: "$replies"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "comments.replies": "$replies"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$postId",
      body: {
        $first: "$body"
      },
      comments: {
        $push: "$comments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Summary of the change**

1. Unwinded both comments and it's replies
2. Added new fields for displaying `isLiked` and `countOfLikes` using `addFields` stage
3. grouped twice to reform original structure of the data(*first grouped by comments then posts*)

https://mongoplayground.net/p/lymCfeIIy9j

Comment: thank you for the answer its very helpful , how can I populate them replies tho

Comment: You may have to handle this in the backend code. SInce `replies` is an array, every programming language can return its length by default. You may not have to project it from the mongo itself

Comment: I understand , but in my case its kindda the best  approach for me now, to get them count and ... from mongodb . if only i could find a way to get into the replies  and add that new value its could be amazing for me

Comment: `comments.replies.countOfLikes` ...is this the path you want to show the count of likes??

Comment: exactly `comments.replies.countOfLikes` and `comments.replies.isLiked`

Comment: can u check now whether the updated answer satisfies your problem

Comment: sorry for the delay i was praying. its re turns only the first element in the post array

Comment: did u check the playground I attached

Comment: or maybe you need to ` preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` in your unwind stages to use left join instead inner join

Comment: ``preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true``  very helpful  worked. but how ama gonna populate the post for example with other file createdAt field that i have already in the db , have a lot of other field but all them return null

Comment: Hey I can help you with this current question only. it is like you are asking here to fix all your problems at once. The best approach is to split your problems into multiple questions and post so that others might also be helpful to you

Comment: okay cool thank you very very  much, i really really appreciate your answer , but the one last thing , plz,  is just to populate the post only with existing field. and then i am gonna accept it as the answer and upvote it.

Comment: haha okay.. what is your current problem again?

Comment: haha.. thank you. I have everything i need , but  all them field posts that i have in my db are not showing up beside the body when i try to add other posts filed its return null. same as ` "replies.countOflikes"` and  `"replies.isLiked" `

Comment: you have to pass all the fields from higher stages to lower stages just like `body: { $first:"$body" }` Note: you have to do this in both the group stages

Comment: example: inside both the group stages you need to add `createdAt : { $first:"$createdAt" }`

Comment: thank you man, god bless you , in your life and you career.

Comment: i have this new question can you check it out ?

Comment: send the link. I can have a look at it

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682883/how-to-normalize-state-in-redux-using-normalizr/67695362#67695362)