# How to Normalize state in redux using Normalizr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a nested array of objects like this:

```
var posts = [
   {
     _id:1234,
     body:"text",
     comments:[
        {
         _id:234,
         body:"hello world",  {
         ]
       },
       {
         _id:434,
         body:"hello world",
         replies:[
            {
              _id:0e2345,
              body:"hello",
            {
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

I want to use normalizr to simplify array and use with redux. I have read the Normalizr documentation but it has few examples and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried the following code without success. The result I get is an array with undefined.

```
export function getPosts(state, action) {
  const { payload } = action;
  const { data} = payload;
  const normalized = new schema.Entity("posts", {}, { idAttribute: "_id",});
  const normalizedData = normalize(data, [normalized]);

  return {
    ...state,
    normalizedData,
  };
}
```

I need something like this:

```
entities:{
    posts:{
       123:{
        _id:123,
        body:"hello world",
        comments:{
          234:{
            _id:234,
            body:"hello world",
            replies:{
              0e2345:{
              _id:0e2345,
              body:"oh no"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this using a JSON object:

```
[{
    "_id":1234,
    "body":"text",
    "comments":[
       {
        "_id":234,
        "body":"hello world"  }
        ]
},
      {
        "_id":434,
        "body":"hello world",
        "replies":[
           {
             "_id":0e2345,
             "body":"hello"
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And making the structure in the code:

```
import data from "./data.json";
import { normalize, schema } from "normalizr";

const _id = new schema.Entity('_id');
const body = new schema.Entity('body');

  const normalized = new schema.Entity("posts", {
    posts:{
      _id:{
        _id:_id,
        body:body,
        comments:{
          _id:{
            _id:_id,
            body:body,
            replies:{
              _id:{
              _id:_id,
              body:body
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
  });
  
const normalizedData = normalize(data, [normalized]);

console.log(normalizedData);
```

I get the next [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM0rl.png).